# Jquery Window reload waits for another(target _blank) to close before it reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reload current page but should open a new window before the reload happens.

Then new window opens corectly but the old window waits for the new window to close before it reloads.

I want the reload to happen even if the new window isn't closed.

```
window.open(location.protocol + '//' + location. hostname + : + location.port + '/print_receipt/' + res[0], '_blank');

location.reload()
```

Comment: Well sounds like window.open is blocking and I highly doubt there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Firefox?

Comment: No clue what "closed" means since there is no closing in your code.

Comment: The closed has to do with the new window. The old window hangs up on reload unless u close the new tab.

Comment: I'm using chrome. I tried on fire firefox and found it works well. So the issue has to do with chrome. Any suggestion to fix on chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but:

You can access the onload method of the new window this way, so when new window finishes loading it will refresh current window.

```
const res = ["#res0"];
const newTab = window.open(location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+ ':' +location.port+'/print_receipt/'+res[0], '_blank');

newTab.onload = function() {
   location.reload();
}
```

PS: Also you were missing quotation marks in the link `location.hostname + ':' + location.port`

Comment: I tested my code in firefox and it works but not on chrome.